# imprimir todos los datos de un array en un highcharts

Tags: php, javascript, highcharts

Hola tengo un pequeño problema con highcharts logre que en el gráfico se muestren la ultima área, de las cuarenta áreas el problema es que no logro que se recorra el arreglo completo para que se muestren todos mi código es el siguiente:

```
 case 5:
        //lineal
        $consulta = $obj->getQueryConsulta();
        $result = $catalogo->obtenerLista($consulta);
        $datos = array();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $datos[$row['datos']] = $row['series'];
        }
        print_r($datos);
    $menu = count($datos);



        echo "<script>Highcharts.chart('container', {

title: {
    text: '" . $obj->getDescripcion() . "'
},

subtitle: {
    text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
},

yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: '" . $obj->getDescripcion() . "'
    }
},
legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'middle'
},

plotOptions: {
    series: {
        label: {
            connectorAllowed: false
        },
        pointStart: 2010
    }
},";

        foreach ($datos as $key => $value) {

            echo "series: [{

    name: '" . $key . "',";
            echo ' data: [';

            echo"$value]

";
            echo"}";
            echo"],";

            echo" ";
        }
        echo "
responsive: {
    rules: [{
        condition: {
            maxWidth: 500
        },
        chartOptions: {
            legend: {
                layout: 'horizontal',
                align: 'center',
                verticalAlign: 'bottom'
            }
        }
    }]
}});  </script>";
        break;
```

El highcharts solamente muestra la última area del array

```
Array ( [Dirección] => 1 [Sistemas] => 25 [Comunicación Social] => 0   [Desarrollo Institucional] => 0 [S. Técnica] => 3 [Indicadores] => 0 [Exhibición] => 0 [Registro] => 0 [Fotografía] => 0 [Comunicación] => 1 [Difusión] => 1 [Electrónicos] => 0 [Prensa] => 0 [Mediación] => 0 [Académicos] => 0 [Editorial] => 0 [Arquitectura] => 0 [Museografía] => 0 [Administración] => 0 [Presupuesto] => 0 [R. Humanos] => 0 [R. Materiales] => 0 [R. Financieros] => 0 [Jurídico] => 0 [Custodios] => 0 [Amigos P.] => 0 [Seguridad] => 0 [Amigos D. E.] => 0 [Amigos S.] => 0 [Contabilidad P.] => 0 [Tienda] => 0 [Cultura] => 0 [INBA] => 0 [Taquilla] => 0 [Archivo] => 0 [Servicios al Público] => 0 [Servicio Social] => 0 [Diseño] => 0 [Proyectos Especiales] => 0 [Personal de Museo] => 0 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que debe de poner `series` afuera del bucle asi:

```
echo "series[";
foreach ($datos as $key => $value) {
        echo "{
                name: '" . $key . "',";
        echo '  data: [';
        echo   "$value]";
        echo"},";            
}
echo "],";
```

Comment: ya lo agregue y ahora no muestra el grafico